# With a standard non-administrator user can I set a registry key at run-time in the background?

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey, setvalue

Will i need any specific privileges to run a setValue of a Registry Key in C# in HKEY_CURRENT_USER .

example: RegKey.SetValue("Key", "");

Comment: You should be able to.. Did you try?

Comment: The problem is that it is really hard to set up what i am working on and I created a user but it's HKEY_CURRENT_USER doesn't have all of the keys that my administrator user has. Another problem is that I don't know exactly what kind of user the customer will be using so I can't create a user just like they are because I don't know the type of user they will use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is not easy thing to do, but here is the workaround. 
The problem is that it is really hard to set up what i am working on and I created a user but it's HKEY_CURRENT_USER doesn't have all of the keys that my administrator user has. Another problem is that I don't know exactly what kind of user the customer will be using so I can't create a user just like they are because I don't know the type of user they will use